# C-Style Character String

Tags: c++

I want to connect two C-style character strings and store the result in a dynamic char array.

```
int main()
{
  char word1[] = "hello";
  char word2[] = "haha";
  auto ptr = new char[20];
  strcpy(ptr,strcat(word1,word2));
  cout<<ptr<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler says there is a "segmentation fault" at the statement `strcpy(ptr,strcat(word1,word2));`. Why does the compiler say that?

Comment: the segfault is not from your compiler but when you run the executable. A segfault reported while you run the compiler would be a bug in your compiler

Comment: You got the order wrong; you want `strcat(strcpy(ptr, word1), word2);`

Comment: `auto ptr = new char[20];` is overly complex here. `char buf[20];` is all that's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
strcpy(ptr, word1);
strcat(ptr, word2);
```

You need to use `ptr` for both operations, the copy and the concatenation.

In your version `strcat(word1,word2)` tries to concatenate `word2`after the end of `word1`. But there is no accessible memory there, so you get a segmentation fault.